# adding a number to list from a file im reading

Tags: python, list

hi im trying to add numbers to a list from a txt file im reading that contain numbers
ex 12 31 22 45 86
but im getting the following error

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12 31 22 45 86'

```
fileName= input("Enter the File name that has the X values : ")
inputFile= open(fileName, 'r')

xs=[]

for num in inputFile:
    num = num.strip()
    number= int(num)
    xs.append(number)

print(xs)
mu = xs.mean()
```

Comment: @wts the error message is clear, OP is trying to convert a string containing _several_ integers. like ìnt("1 2 3")`, this won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't preform int on a string. Instead split the string by spaces and use map to turn all elements in the new list to an int.

```
inputFile= open('test.txt', 'r')
xs = []
for num in inputFile:
    xs.extend(list(map(int,num.strip().split())))
print(xs)
```

Comment: `.extend` will acceptable an iterable, so `xs.extend(map(int,num.strip().split()))` works too.